# PhantomJS not found on Shiny Server

Tags: r, ubuntu, phantomjs, plotly, shiny-server

I'm using plotly's export function to generate png graphs. 
I installed Shiny Server on an Ubuntu 14.04.

It works on my local computer. 
It works when I open R from console on the server. However, when I run Shiny app on server, I get PhantomJS error.

```
PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

I already installed PhantomJS and since I can produce images via R console, i think it exists in PATH.

How can I fix this problem or how can I test to find the problemmatic point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, install the `webshot` package from the terminal on the Ubuntu server:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('webshot')\""
```

Next, follow the [installation description](https://gist.github.com/telbiyski/ec56a92d7114b8631c906c18064ce620#file-install-phantomjs-2-1-1-ubuntu) of `phantomJS`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev -y
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev -y
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev -y
cd ~
export PHANTOM_JS="phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64"
wget https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v2.1.1/$PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
sudo tar xvjf $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
sudo mv $PHANTOM_JS /usr/local/share
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin
phantomjs --version
```

With this, you should be able use `webshot` and `phantomJS` with a Shiny App.

I have tested it with a small sample test app, which I added to `/srv/shiny-server/`:

the `ui.R` looks like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Test App to display webshot"),

  # Sidebar layout
  sidebarLayout(


    sidebarPanel(

      #actually useless part

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: screenshot ----
      imageOutput("webshot_image")

    )
  )
)
```

the `server.R` looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$webshot_image <- renderImage({
    # A temp file to save the output.
    # This file will be removed later by renderImage
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext = '.png')

    # Generate the PNG
    webshot::webshot(url = "https://github.com/rstudio/shiny",
                     file = outfile)

    # Return a list containing the filename
    list(src = outfile,
         contentType = 'image/png',
         width = 400,
         height = 300,
         alt = "This is alternate text")
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)

}
```

The final result is this:

[image: output_snapshot]